# sigma algebra of a subset by the inverse of a function

Tags: measure-theory

X,Y sets and f:X->Y a fuction. Let A be a class of subsets from Y. The sigma algebra generated by f^(-1)(A) its the same as the inverse by f of the sigma algebra generated by A?